# Auto conversion of foreign key from string to ObjectId to make $lookup aggregation work by MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

I have two collections and I am using one of collections `_id` field as [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in other collection. But `_id` is `Object` and in in other collection it is `string` so `$lookup` is not able to match.

Collection 1: `User collection`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6471bf9db77f0b33a9b0bd38"), "name" : "Alok", "city" : "someCity" }
```

Collection 2: `Order collection`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6471bfd4b77f0b33a9b0bd39"), "uid" : "6471bf9db77f0b33a9b0bd38", "product" : "product1" }
```

I am trying to use `$lookup`

```
db.order.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: 'users', localField:'uid', foreignField:'_id', as:'join'}}])
```

This `$lookup` does not work because `_id` is Object and `uid` is string.

This is common requirement so there must be some automated way as I dont want to use $lookup with long pipeline.

What can quickest fix to make this `$lookup` work without using long `pipeline`?

Comment: Before $lookup stage you need to set the `uid` field as ObjectId. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vABHXdVa9db)

Comment: Why not be consistent and store them both as ObjectIds which avoids this problem altogether?

Comment: @YongShun: your comment is a good answer. you should post that as answer :)

Comment: @user20042973: I was not aware of good practice of Mongodb. Now I am realizing to read good practice on foreign key in mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you need a `$set` stage to convert the `uid` to `ObjectId` type before `$lookup` stage.

```
db.order.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      uid: {
        $toObjectId: "$uid"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "uid",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "join"
    }
  }
])
```

Otherwise, you may use `$lookup` with pipeline as well.

```
db.order.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        uid: {
          $toObjectId: "$uid"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$uid"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "join"
    }
  }
])
```